# por que min-height no agarra el porcentaje del tamaño de su contenedor padre?

Tags: css

tengo un div llamado contact__form al que le coloque un min-height de 500px y el hijo es un form con un min-height de 90%, se supone que ese form deberia agarrar un altura minima de 450px pero no.

este es mi codigo html:

```
    <section class="contact">
    <h4 class="title">
        <span class="title__content">CONTACTO</span>
    </h4>
    <div class="contact__form">
        <form id="form" action="https://formsubmit.co/" method = "POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nombre" required>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <img src="laptop.svg" class="contact__img">
    <div class="contact__redes">
        <a href="#" class="contact__link"><img class="contact__icon" src="whatsapp-brands.svg">Whatsapp</a>
        <a href="#" class="contact__link"><img class="contact__icon" src="twitter-brands.svg">Twitter</a>
        <a href="#" class="contact__link"><img class="contact__icon" src="github-brands.svg">Github</a>
        <a href="#" class="contact__link"><img class="contact__icon" src="envelope-solid.svg">Gmail</a>
        <a href="#" class="contact__link"><img class="contact__icon" src="linkedin-brands.svg">Linkedin</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

mi codigo css:

```
    @media all and ( max-width: 800px){

    .contact{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .contact__form{
        min-height: 500px;
    }

    form{
        min-height: 90%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido Gunta! Nos seria mucho más facil ayudarte si además de css nos adjuntaras el html. las capturas de pantalla hay que intentar evitarlas. 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Takyo para la siguiente, junta esto [ ask ] ... vas a tener el link magico [ask] ;)

Comment: Gunta, por favor añade el codigo HTML mas el CSS para poder replicar el problema. Elimina las imagenes, dado que sobran acá.

Comment: No recuerdo si el formulario tiene la propiedad `display` por defecto como bloque. Si no, habrá que especificarla y, seguramente, establecer márgenes internos (padding) y externos (margin) y/o probar con [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) para mostrarlo correctamente.

Comment: El ```min-height``` no se define en **%** sino en ```px```

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/min-height segun esto si lo acepta

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que, al ```min-height``` del ```form``` dale igual que el padre: ```min-height: 500px```. Si no funciona  y si eso es todo tu **CSS**, dale ```display:flex``` al padre de ```form```.

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz si lo modifique para que el contact__form tuviera un height de 100vh y el form con un height de 90% y ahi si lo agarro, de todas formas no entiendo por que se ignoraba lo anterior que habia hecho, ahora deberia elimanar mi pregunta o la dejo alli?

Comment: No elimines. Realiza otra pregunta con tu código nuevo que funciona y marca como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

modifique el height de contact__form y me sirvio asi

```
@media all and ( max-width: 800px){
/*--------contact---------------*/

.contact{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.contact__form{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

}